# How to find what pylance considers Python stdlib?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

While using Python with visual studio code, I’ve seen pylance mention stdlib.

What does pylance consider python’s stdlib?
I’m guessing it looks for stdlib dir based on some setting, but I don’t know what the setting is, where to find it, or what it’s currently set to.

Comment: What is "VCA code"?

Comment: Could you please give an example to explain what you saw more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You may read this page on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/pull/4132) about showing a warning when a stdlib module is being overridden.

This will not affect you editing your code. You can add the following codes to your settings.json to close the warning:

```
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
      "reportShadowedImports": "none"
  },
```

Comment: I've seen this.  It does not answer my question.  I want to know what pylance is considering the "stdlib" and where the "stdlib" is located.

Comment: Ask for the developer on github may be a good choice.